# Mapping column with space in name from stored procedure to .net model

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, .net-framework-version

I'm having issues pulling a value from a stored procedure to be show in my .net view. As far as I can see it is down to the space in the name.

The part of the stored procedure which gets the date, is:

```
DATEDIFF(n, d.DateStarted, GetUtcDate()) AS [Time Taken]
```

This works fine when running in sql, and I can get the other values it returns to show in my program.

The relevant part of the model is as follows:

```
[Column("Time Taken")]
public int TimeTaken {get; set; }
```

The procedure is being ran by the following code:

```
public IList RunStoreProc()
{
   IList result;
   result = db.Database.SqlQuery<ModelName>("[Monitoring.RunStoreProc]").ToList();
   return result;
}
```

I have tried mapping the column name using [Column("Column Name")]. This did not work. Neither did changing the type in the model from int to datetime or string.

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Thank you in advance.